# Запись в файл всех комбинаций

Tags: python

Есть код для вывода комбинации пин-кода

```
from itertools import product
for combos in product('0123456789', repeat=4):
    S = ''.join(combos)
    if S.find('BC') == -1 and  S.find('CC') == -1:
        filee = open("pins.txt", "w")
        filee.write(S)
        filee.close()
```

В txt файле только одна комбинация "9999"

Как вывести все комбинации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [1]: from itertools import product

In [2]: combinations = []

In [3]: for combos in product("0123456789", repeat=4):
   ...:     combinations.append("".join(combos))
   ...:

In [4]: with open("data.txt", "w") as fp:
   ...:     fp.write("\n".join(combinations))
```

Comment: Объясните, зачем добавлять `In [1]:` и т.п. перед кодом? Чтобы было сложнее скопировать? :)

Comment: Эм, это делает ipython.

Comment: Так может не стоит использовать его для ответов на стековерфлоу или как-то удалять перед вставкой в ответ?

Comment: Нет. Пусть либо копирует и чистит, либо переписывает ручками (что полезнее).

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы открываете файл так:  `open("file.txt", "w")` вы уничтожаете старый файл, создаёте новый пустой и пишете в него.

Из за постоянного переоткрытия файла в цикле вы постоянно перезаписываете старый. Вот у вас и есть результат только от последней итерации.

Лучше открывайте файл перед циклом - это уменьшит кол-во обращений к диску и увеличит скорость работы программы.

Но если вы все же хотите постоянно переоткрывать файл - используйте: `open ("file.txt", "a")`. Это будет дописывать в конец файла новые данные.